# Remove all special characters from a string in R?

Tags: regex, string, r, character

How to remove all special characters from string in R and replace them with spaces ?

Some special characters to remove are : `~!@#$%^&*(){}_+:"<>?,./;'[]-=`

I've tried `regex` with `[:punct:]` pattern but it removes only punctuation marks.

Question 2 : And how to remove characters from foreign languages like : `â í ü Â á ą ę ś ć` ?

Answer : Use `[^[:alnum:]]` to remove`~!@#$%^&*(){}_+:"<>?,./;'[]-=` and use `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` to remove also `â í ü Â á ą ę ś ć` in `regex` or `regexpr` functions.

**Solution in base R :**

```
x <- "a1~!@#$%^&*(){}_+:\"<>?,./;'[]-=" 
gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", x)  # no libraries needed
```

Comment: What is the definition of "special character"?

Comment: My own definition would be every character that isn't in Unicode ;-). But I guess many other people would disagree.

Comment: Maybe take a look at `sub` or `gsub` functions.

Comment: regex [:punct:] going to make half of the job or mayby all

Answer (score 268, accepted):

You need to use [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) to identify the unwanted characters.  For the most easily readable code, you want the [`str_replace_all`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/topics/str_replace_all) from the [`stringr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/index.html) package, though [`gsub`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/grep) from base R works just as well.

The exact regular expression depends upon what you are trying to do.  You could just remove those specific characters that you gave in the question, but it's much easier to remove all punctuation characters.

```
x <- "a1~!@#$%^&*(){}_+:\"<>?,./;'[]-=" #or whatever
str_replace_all(x, "[[:punct:]]", " ")
```

(The base R equivalent is `gsub("[[:punct:]]", " ", x)`.)

An alternative is to swap out all non-alphanumeric characters.

```
str_replace_all(x, "[^[:alnum:]]", " ")
```

Note that the definition of what constitutes a letter or a number or a punctuatution mark varies slightly depending upon your locale, so you may need to experiment a little to get exactly what you want.

Comment: nice answers +1  You may want to replace the `" "` with `""` otherwise you have empty white space in the string.

Comment: @TylerRinker: True, though QBik did specifically ask for spaces.

Comment: How to delete remowe those crazy characters : `â í ü Â á` ?

Comment: You need to read up on regular expressions.  Start with the link in my answer, and then read `?regex` and `?regexpr`.

Comment: Try replacing `[^[:alnum:]]` with `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` or possibly `\\W`.

Comment: The `[[:punct:]]` option does not work sometimes e.g:`str_replace_all("jef|bezos", "[[:punct:]]", " ")` but  `[^[:alnum:]]` works. It is safer for strict situations.

Comment: I have the problem that I can't even save x as stated in your answer @RichieCotton. If x contains any special character my R Studio does nothing else than telling me that I used an unknown escape sequence (none).

Comment: @maxgotstuck You need to double your backslashes need to escape them. For example, instead of including `\r`, include `\\r`.

Comment: now there is `str_remove_all()` in stringr when you need to remove them all.

Answer (score 64):

Instead of using regex to remove those "crazy" characters, just convert them to ASCII, which will remove accents, but will keep the letters.

```
astr <- "Ábcdêãçoàúü"
iconv(astr, from = 'UTF-8', to = 'ASCII//TRANSLIT')
```

which results in

```
[1] "Abcdeacoauu"
```

Comment: I had to add `iconv(astr, from="UFT-8", to="ASCII//TRANSLIT")`, otherwise with french characters like `ç` it goes a bit funny.

Comment: No workee in USA on Windoze, I get an 'NA' ... `Sys.getlocale()` ... ```LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252```

Comment: This worked:  ```str = "Ábcdêãçoàúü"; str = iconv(str, from = '', to = 'ASCII//TRANSLIT'); str;```

Comment: Also It works in windows  `readlines( data, encoding="UTF-8")`

Answer (score 13):

Convert the Special characters to apostrophe,

```
Data  <- gsub("[^0-9A-Za-z///' ]","'" , Data ,ignore.case = TRUE)
```

Below code it to remove extra ''' apostrophe

```
Data <- gsub("''","" , Data ,ignore.case = TRUE)
```

Use `gsub(..)` function for replacing the special character with apostrophe

Comment: What about pre-existing code or comments that *already* contains `''` two consecutive apostrophes? Won't those be affected? Don't those need to be protected/escaped first?

Comment: Also '/' gets through, when it shouldn't.