# R how to remove VERY special characters in strings?

Tags: r, special-characters

I'm trying to remove some VERY special characters in my strings. 
i've read other post like:

1. [Remove all special characters from a string in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294284/remove-all-special-characters-from-a-string-in-r)
2. [How to remove special characters from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552253/how-to-remove-special-characters-from-a-string)

but these are not what im looking for.

lets say my string is as following:

```
s = "who are í ½í¸€ bringing?"
```

i've tried following:

```
test = tm_map(s, function(x) iconv(enc2utf8(x), sub = "byte"))
test = iconv(s, 'UTF-8', 'ASCII')
```

none of above worked.

**edit:**
I am looking for a GENERAL solution!
I cannot (and prefer not) manually identify all the special characters.

also these VERY special characters MAY (not 100% sure) be result from emoticons

please help or guide me to the right posts.
Thank you!

Comment: I think the real question is, how did you and up with gibberish strings? If you take a step backward to how you produced this string, you can probably adjust that step to get the output you want.

Comment: So, I just tried this with gsub, and it appeared to work. Like so: `s2 <- gsub("€", "", s)`. Try doing that. Basically changing "€" instances in your s string to nothing, effectively removing them.

Comment: @RichardScriven im not very sure but MAY be from emoticons

Comment: @giraffehere do u have a more general/less manual way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, I'm going to go ahead and make an answer, because I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
> s = "who are í ½í¸€ bringing?"
> rmSpec <- "í|½|€" # The "|" designates a logical OR in regular expressions.
> s.rem <- gsub(rmSpec, "", s) # gsub replace any matches in remSpec and replace them with "".
> s.rem
[1] "who are  ¸ bringing?"
```

Now, this does have the caveat that you have to manually define the special character in the `rmSpec` variable. Not sure if you know what special characters to remove or if you're looking for a more general solution.

EDIT:

So it appears you almost had it with `iconv`, you were just missing the `sub` argument. See below:

```
> s
[1] "who are í ½í¸€ bringing?"
> s2 <- iconv(s, "UTF-8", "ASCII", sub = "")
> s2
[1] "who are   bringing?"
```

Comment: ya... im looking for a more general solution. manually identifying all the special character is almost impossible in my case (since i have a very large data set and i prefer not going through them one by one to find out which/what special characters i have)

Comment: @alwaysaskingquestions See my edit in my answer. There was an additional argument in `iconv` you were missing.

Comment: You can also specify a group of characters to be replaced like `gsub("[í½€¸]","",s)`, which is simpler than using `|` multiple times

Comment: @thelatemail I always forget this. Thanks for the addition!