# Stringi/stringr pattern behave differently if function is sourced in R

Tags: r, stringr, stringi

I am using the `stringi` package for a while now and everything works fine.

I recently wanted to put some regex inside a function and store that function in a separate file. The code works just fine if the function is loaded from the script but when it is sourced I do not get the expected result.

Here is the code to reproduce the issue :

```
clean <- function(text){
  stri_replace_all_regex(str = text, 
                         pattern = "(?i)[^a-zàâçéèêëîïôûùüÿñæœ0-9,\\.\\?!']",
                         replacement = " ")
}
text <- "A sample text with some french accent é, è, â, û and some special characters |, [, ( that needs to be cleaned."
clean(text) # OK
[1] "A sample text with some french accent é, è, â, û and some special characters  ,  ,   that needs to be cleaned."
source(clean.r)
clean(text) # KO
[1] "A sample text with some french accent  ,  ,  ,   and some special characters  ,  ,   that needs to be cleaned."
```

I want to remove everything that is not a letter, an accented letters and punctuation charcater `?`, `!`, `,`, and `.`.

The code works just fine if the function is loaded inside the script directly. If it is sourced then it gives a different result.

I also tried using `stringr` and I have the same problem. My files are saved in UTF-8 encoding.

I do not understand why this is happening, any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

```
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=French_France.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] stringi_1.1.5     data.table_1.10.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.1 tools_3.4.1    yaml_2.1.14
```

Comment: I am having similar problems. I think it is to do with how the special characters are read when file is sourced. My text contains "£" and yours contain French accents "é, è, â, û".

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the text to ASCII first.  This will change the characters, and may allow the same behaviour when you source the function in R.

+1 to Felipe Alvarenga
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45941699/2069472

```
text <- "Ábcdêãçoàúü"
iconv(text, to = "ASCII//TRANSLIT")
```