# R How to remove special characters â€™ from a data frame column?

Tags: r

Using tidyverse I would like to remove the special characters from "Education" column so that it would just say Masters or Bachelors. Since I'm using Tidyverse I would like to exemplify using piping and keeping the data frame as is:

```
library(tidyverse)
education <- data.frame(Education = c("Masterâ€™s ","Professional ","Bachelorâ€™s"))
education <- sapply(education,str_replace(education,"â€™",""))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove all special characters from a string in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294284/remove-all-special-characters-from-a-string-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `dplyr`

```
data.frame(Education = c("Masterâ€™s ","Professional ","Bachelorâ€™s")) %>% 
   mutate(Education = str_replace(Education,"â€™",""))
      Education
1      Masters 
2 Professional 
3     Bachelors
```

Answer (score 1):

That's what [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) are for:

```
gsub("[^A-Za-z]", "", c("Masterâ€™s ","Professional ","Bachelorâ€™s"))
```

produces:

```
[1] "Masters"      "Professional" "Bachelors"
```

Comment: How do I leverage gsub so that I still get back the dataframe in the same schema but with the changes? The above brings back a vector with "V1" column

Comment: `gsub` takes a vector and returns a vector. You simply assign that returned vector to `Education`, as you did with the original vector.