# Is there a way to replace ′ (prime) in a string using str_replace_all?

Tags: r, replace, unicode, utf-8, stringr

I'm trying to format various coordinates in degrees/minutes and degrees/minutes/seconds prior to passing through measurements::conv_unit(), which requires the input as numbers separated by spaces. I've read various answers to similar questions, such as this one: [Remove all special characters from a string in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294284/remove-all-special-characters-from-a-string-in-r)

Which lead me to initially try:

```
library(tidyverse)
latitude <- "-36°48′31.33"
str_replace_all(string = latitude, pattern = c("°|'|\"|′|″"), repl = " ")
```

**However, the prime symbol (′) is not being removed. Is this an issue with calling the symbol in the argument, or its encoding?**

I have explored other ways of substituting symbols:

```
str_replace_all(string = temp_core$description$latitude, pattern = "[^[:alnum:]]", repl=" ") #removes all symbols including . and -
str_replace_all(string = temp_core$description$latitude, pattern = "[[:punct:]]", repl=" ") #removes most symbols including . and - but excluding °
iconv(temp_core$description$latitude, "utf-8", "ascii", sub = " ") # removes the unwanted symbols but replaces them with an uneven number of spaces
```

But none of these options give me the combination I need: retaining some characters (- and .) while dropping the others. I do prefer the control that pattern = c("°|'|\"|′|″") provides as I am building a database with automated data wrangling and therefore I can specify symbols commonly included in coordinates.

**Is there a simple solution I have missed that uses str_replace_all()? Is the failure indicative of an issue with the encoding of the string?**

Currently running R version 4.0.1 and tidyverse_1.3.0.

Comment: the prime symbol is removed when i run the code

Comment: @maarvd Okay, that tells me that there is something different on my end in terms of encoding. Do you have any other advice?

Comment: @maarvd see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62419815/why-is-r-coercing-to-when-i-try-to-assign-it-as-a-simple-character-vector-bu