# How to modify special symbol in data frame in r

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

Want to remove all special symbol in data frame in r

The data is:

`No str count`

`1 car. 2`

`1 .car 1`

`2 fish# 1`

`2 car 1`

It should be:

`No str count`

`1 car 3`

`1 . 2`

`2 fish 1`

`2 car 1`

`2 # 1`

I have tried to split it but it doesn't work

Can anyone help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10294818/7547327

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove all special characters from a string in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294284/remove-all-special-characters-from-a-string-in-r)

Comment: How did your data go from 4 rows to 5? And why would you remove the period in "car." but not ".car", and introduce a special character in the last row when you say you want to remove them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try this `base R` solution:

```
#Code
df$str <- trimws(gsub('#','',df$str,fixed = T),whitespace = '\\.')
```

Output:

```
df
  No  str count
1  1  car     2
2  1  car     1
3  2 fish     1
4  2  car     1
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(No = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), str = c("car.", ".car", 
"fish#", "car"), count = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Or this:

```
#Code2
df$str <- gsub('[[:punct:]]','',df$str)
```

Output:

```
df
  No  str count
1  1  car     2
2  1  car     1
3  2 fish     1
4  2  car     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this work:

```
> df
  No   str count
1  1  car.     2
2  1  .car     1
3  2 fish#     1
4  2   car     1
> df$str <- gsub('[.#]','',df$str)
> df
  No  str count
1  1  car     2
2  1  car     1
3  2 fish     1
4  2  car     1
>
```

We can also use Duck's code without gsub:

```
> df
  No   str count
1  1  car.     2
2  1  .car     1
3  2 fish#     1
4  2   car     1
> df$str <- trimws(df$str, whitespace = '[\\.#]')
> df
  No  str count
1  1  car     2
2  1  car     1
3  2 fish     1
4  2  car     1
>
```